# Get column name with last valid value for each index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like this -

```
   A    B    C
0  1  NaN  3.0
1  2  3.0  NaN
2  2  NaN  NaN
3  NaN NaN 53
```

I need to find the column name with the last valid value for each index. For example for the above dataframe, I want to get output something like this.

```
['C','B','A','C]
```

I did try to get the column names but was only able to grab the values by using `iteritems()` on the transpose of the dataframe. Also since It loops through the dataframe, I don't find it very optimal. Please find my approach below

```
l_val = []
for idx, row in df.T.iteritems():
    last_val = None
    for x in row:
        if not pd.isna(x):
            last_val = x
    l_val.append(last_val)
```

Returns -

```
[3.0, 3.0, 2.0]
```

I have tried searching a lot but most answers referred to `last_valid_index` method which would return the last valid index in a column which I don't get if I can use for my problem. Can someone please suggest me any fast way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
df.idxmax(axis=1).to_list()
```

Output:

```
['C', 'B', 'A', 'C']
```

**EDIT:**

For the solution which I showed above you will get the index of maximum value. However you can also have a dataframe where values in first columns are greater than values in columns at the end. Then I would suggest using the solution below to get index of last valid value:

```
df.T.apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index).to_list()
```

Output:

```
['C', 'B', 'A', 'C']
```

Comment: Thanks, let me quickly try on my dataframe.

Comment: When I run it on my df, it throws an error with "TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype"

Comment: This error occurs when type of data is not numeric. You could try: df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore') and then trying again or just using the second solution I provided in the edited answer.

Comment: I think the updated solution works just amazing. Thanks a lot. No need for anything else :)